# Some fundamental results in QFTs

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, pauli-exclusion-principle, quantum-anomalies, ward-identity

In quantum theory we have some principles that guides us, e.g. Pauli's principle. What I am after in this question is a list of fundamental results, be it equation or identities that must hold in a respectable QFT. I am thinking for instance of the Wards identities or Adler-Bell-Jackiw anomaly and similar things.

Please could you make a list of these types of identities and comment on how fundamental these are (say on a scale 1-3 normalized such that Pauli=1).

Also, please comment on how these identities arise and if there are any analogs of these in other theories (e.g. in the classical limit, or in String Theory or whatever)

Finally I would appreciate if you comment on and discuss what would happen in a theory where the pertinent identities are not satisfied.

Please don't close this question as being vague and not explicitly a solvable problem. In my opinion, these types of question are also needed here, apart from the usual "why is F=ma"-questions.

Comment: High level questions are great, but not ones that would take an entire book to answer. I'd recommend splitting the question up a bit and removing the purely opinion-based part (fundamental ranking from 1-3). I see 3 great questions here that should probably stand on their own.

Comment: I edited this out of the question but an putting it as a comment to maintain the original intent of the poster: "
Please don't close this question as being vague and not explicitly a solvable problem. In my opinion, these types of question are also needed here, apart from the usual "why is F=ma"-questions. "

Comment: A classic one thinks of: 't Hooft anomaly matching. From unitarity we get the optical theorem, Froissart bound, the a-theorem, Cutkosky rules, BCFW... In specific theories, there are much stronger principles: in QCD there are sum rules, scattering factorizes etc. Specific quantities in SUSY theories have nonrenormalization theorems, those are also very strong results.

Comment: @tgp2114: Oh, shoo. This question is perfectly fine.

Comment: Shoe${}{}{}{}$.

Comment: If the question is too broad as it stands, it could be restricted to QFT in 3+1 dimensions.